# MultipartFormDataContent doesn't work for greater than about 22 bytes file

Tags: c#, .net, file-upload, multipartform-data

I am trying to use MultipartFormDataContent to upload a file to a server but for some reason, it's working for very small file like "22 bytes" but not larger. so it's working for very small text file but not image or video.

This is the coed :

```
    static Encoding ISO_8859_1 { get { return Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1"); } }
    public static void UploadFile(string _uploadEndPoint, string _fileToUpload, string userName, string password)
    {
        using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            string _auth = string.Format("{0}:{1}", userName, password);
            string _enc = Convert.ToBase64String(ISO_8859_1.GetBytes(_auth));
            string _cred = string.Format("{0} {1}", "Basic", _enc);
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", _enc);
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue.Parse("text/html"));
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue.Parse("application/xhtml+xml"));
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue.Parse("application/xml;q=0.9"));
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue.Parse("image/webp"));
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue.Parse("*/*;q=0.8"));
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.UserAgent.ParseAdd("user-agent");
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Upgrade.ParseAdd("1");



            using (MultipartFormDataContent content = new MultipartFormDataContent())
            {
                using (FileStream stream = File.Open(_fileToUpload, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                {
                    using (StreamContent streamConent = CreateFileContent(stream, _fileToUpload.Split('\\').Last(), "application/octet-stream"))

                    {
                        content.Add(new StringContent("upload"), "submit");
                        content.Add(new StringContent(""), "directory");
                        content.Add(new StringContent(_fileToUpload.Split('\\').Last()), "filename");
                        content.Add(new StringContent("as_json"), "options");
                        content.Add(streamConent);
                        var taskUpload = httpClient.PostAsync(_uploadEndPoint, content);
                        taskUpload.Wait();
                        if (taskUpload.Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("File uploaded");
                            Console.WriteLine(taskUpload.Result.ToString());
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }



    private static StreamContent CreateFileContent(Stream stream, string fileName, string contentType)
    {
        var fileContent = new StreamContent(stream, 4 * 1024);
        fileContent.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("form-data")
        {
            Name = "\"file\"",
            FileName = "\"" + fileName + "\""
        };
        fileContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue(contentType);
        return fileContent;
    }
```

Comment: Set ContentLength header value.

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: I added to "CreateFileContent" method this code ` var length = stream.Length;
            fileContent.Headers.Add("Content-Length", length.ToString());`  but it didn't work ..

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?